# Return to selected page after macro runs

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have the below macro which copies two cells into a different page then prints them to a label,

```
Sub Tag_75()
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 1).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 1).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")

'Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1:A2").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").WrapText = True
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Font.Size = 22
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").ShrinkToFit = True

Dim STDprinter As String

STDprinter = Application.ActivePrinter
'Application.ActivePrinter = "\\SBS2011\Xerox WorkCentre 7830 on Ne06:"
Application.ActivePrinter = "\\JCSP55J\DYMO LabelWriter 450 (Copy 2) on Ne05:"
ActiveSheet.PrintOut
Application.ActivePrinter = STDprinter

End Sub
```

Can someone help me with returning to the original sheet im on when running the macro.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember where you came from:

```
Sub Tag_75()
dim sh as worksheet
Set sh = Activesheet

ActiveCell.Resize(1, 1).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 1).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")

'Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1:A2").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").WrapText = True
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Font.Size = 22
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").ShrinkToFit = True

Dim STDprinter As String

STDprinter = Application.ActivePrinter
'Application.ActivePrinter = "\\SBS2011\Xerox WorkCentre 7830 on Ne06:"
Application.ActivePrinter = "\\JCSP55J\DYMO LabelWriter 450 (Copy 2) on Ne05:"
ActiveSheet.PrintOut
Application.ActivePrinter = STDprinter

sh.Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not using `Selection` at all.  It is rarely necessary.  For example (not debugged):

```
Sub Tag_75()
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 1).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 1).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")

'Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
with Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2")
    .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
End With

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").WrapText = True
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Font.Size = 22
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").ShrinkToFit = True

Dim STDprinter As String

STDprinter = Application.ActivePrinter
'Application.ActivePrinter = "\\SBS2011\Xerox WorkCentre 7830 on Ne06:"
Application.ActivePrinter = "\\JCSP55J\DYMO LabelWriter 450 (Copy 2) on Ne05:"
ActiveSheet.PrintOut
Application.ActivePrinter = STDprinter

End Sub
```